# Match the characters that are in quotes followed by the word xyz_id

Tags: regex

It is necessary to match the string set into quotes that is followed by the world `"xyz_id":` For example the text is like this: `"xyz_id":"55555"` It's necessary to get only 55555 with a regular expression..

Comment: Which programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex will help you extract "55555":

```
\"xyz_id\":\"(.*)\"
```

https://regex101.com/r/5VnGKN/1

Below is sample code in Java:

```
            String x = "\"xyz_id\":\"55555\""; //String on which processing needs to be done
            Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("\"xyz_id\":\"(.*)\""); //Pattern to compare
            Matcher mat1 = pat1.matcher(x);       
            while(mat1.find()){
                System.out.println(mat1.group(1));
            }
```

Output:

```
55555
```

Comment: Thank you @Mukesh this line solved specifically my issue: `System.out.println(mat1.group(1));` as I did not know that I could select a group with the language used, I was looking to do it with the same regular expression and this approach had me in trouble. Then after I realized this I found a way to use it in JavaScript too with this answer:[link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/3363138[/link]

Comment: Welcome... Glad to help. Please include language tags too so that people can provide Language specific answer.